# TeXLive: Error; for better info unpack, then run install-tl-windows.bat

Tags: errors, texlive

I downloaded and run the file `install-tl-windows.exe`, but after hours later I received this error:

```
Error; for better info unpack, then run install-tl-windows.bat or install-tl-advanced.bat.
```

Now I do not know what went wrong. What should I do now?

The `texlive` folder in `C:\` is 5.20 GB. I am running windows 10

I am attaching the snapshot of error and [install-tl.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IIb9wKU24l3hsfHfp9ns51e70Pkuiypf) file

[image]

Comment: If you can start tlmgr in the new installation try to find the problematic package and reinstall it. Otherwise you have to reinstall TeX Live. Hint: Use the advanced installer and install the minimal scheme first (later on you can use tlmgr to  install the rest, that's more stable).

Comment: I can start `tlmgr`, but i do not know how to find the problematic package.

Comment: Could you please post the installation log so that we can see where the error is?

Comment: log file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IIb9wKU24l3hsfHfp9ns51e70Pkuiypf

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the `install-tl.zip` file and running the `install-tl-advanced.bat` with admin rights did the trick for me.